# Mocking issue for getBoundingClientRect

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

How to mock this line of code. I have a config (i.e mockConfig) with host property of any type. But it has html element. So that I can use querySelector and getBoundingClientRect methods. but I couldn't able to mock getBoundingClientRect.

```
//this.config.host='<div><i class="icon-dropdown"></i></div>'
..
const arrowHostLoc = (this.config.host as HTMLElement).querySelector('.icon-dropdown').getBoundingClientRect();
```

Code I'm using

```
  const mockConfig = {
    contentType: TestComponent,
    contentConfig: contentConfig,
    cssClass: 'rainbow',
    alignment: 'center',
    topPadding: 5,
    scrollListener: scrollSubject.asObservable(),
    host: { //type of any
      getBoundingClientRect: hostGetBoundClientRectSpy
    }
  } as IPopoverConfig;

--------------------

describe('xxx',()=>{
...
mockConfig.host = document.createElement('div');
spyOn('mockConfig.host.querySelector',['getBoundingClientRect']).and.returnValue(new DOMRect(0,0,0,0));
});
```

But i'm getting error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null`.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
spyOn('mockConfig.host.querySelector',['getBoundingClientRect']).and.returnValue(new DOMRect(0,0,0,0));
```

I used

```
spyOn(Element.prototype,['getBoundingClientRect']).and.callFake(
jasmine.createSpy('getBoundingClientRect').and.returnValue({ top: 1, height: 100, left: 2, width: 200, right: 202 })
);
```

This solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your host doesn't have a `querySelector`. `querySelector` comes as undefined so you need to mock it too.

Either give host explicity the type of `HTMLElement` so it has the querySelector or mock it like below:

```
...
host :{
querySelector: {
 getBoundingClientRect: hostGetBoundClientRectSpy
}
}
```

Comment: In my `describe` i'm re-assigning the `config.host` with an html element which has querySelector. The only problem was I forgot how to mock `getBoundingClientRect`.  Now I fixed it. thanks :)

Comment: yes the `querySelector` you were assigning didn't have the `getBoundingClientRect`